# How come the commutator of $J^2$ (momentum) and $J^{\pm}$ (ladder operator) is zero while they don't have simultaneous eigenfunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator, lie-algebra

We know that $J^2$ has eigenfunctions which are the spherical harmonics, and these spherical harmonics definitely aren't eigenfunctions for $J^+$, because $J^+$ acting on one spherical harmonic increases it's "$m$" by 1. Hence, we can say that $J^2$ and $J^+$ don't have same eigenfunctions. Yet we see that the commutator of $J^2$ and $J^+$ is equal to zero which means they are compatible! Meaning they have simultaneous eigenfunctions. Contradiction. Where is the flaw I made?

Comment: @DavideMorgante $J_\pm$ only have $0$ as eigenvalue. They don't have an eigenbasis (they are jordan blocks with zero eigenvalue).

Comment: @DavideMorgante being Hermitian is not the relevant point, it's being 'normal'. Which the $J^{\pm}$ are not, so the spectral theorem does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

The $J_+$ operators *do not* change the eigenstates for $J^2$ operators. Usually, in the systems you mentioned the eigenstates are characterised by two operators $J^2$ and $J_z$. Hence each state has two labels $|m,j> $. m is the eignevalue for $J_z$.

But you see, states with different $m$ values but same $j$ values are indistinguishable by the operator $J^2$ since it's only sensitive to $j$ value. So each eigenstate of $J^2$ is actually a degenerate state comprising of $(2j+1)$ number of distinct $J_z$ eigenstates. And the operator $J_{\pm}$ changes one of these states to the other. So, that doesn't really change the eigenstate of $J^2$. Hence, it's consistent.

Comment: Note that $J_\pm$ do *not* have an eigenbasis. The only eigenvectors are highest/lowest vectors in each $j$-block, with eigenvalue zero.

Comment: @fqq Of course. I interpreted the question not as "What happens to $J_+$ eigenstates?" but as "if these $J_+$ operators take the state out of an eigenstate of $J^2$. Which they can't!

Comment: still, I think your first sentence is wrong, or at least confusing. There are eigenstates of $J^2$ which are not eigenstates of $J_\pm$ and vice versa.

Comment: Agreed. It was confusing. Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Even before we get to the Casimir $\vec{J}^2$ there is an obstacle: The raising/lowering operators $J_{\pm}=J^{\dagger}_{\mp}$ are not [normal operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator), and hence not diagonalizable in an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors/eigenfunctions (except for a 1-dimensional Hilbert space ${\cal H}\cong \mathbb{C}$ or a 0-dimensional Hilbert space ${\cal H}\cong \{0\}$).